# Save a form with Django from a view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I need to save a **form** with Django from my **views**. I'm geting data from an API and need to save direct on my database:

```
form = NewSubject()
#API request
form.owner = request.user
#Another fields
form.teacher = teacher
form.group = request.user.group
form.save()
```

But I get:

> **Exception Value**: NOT NULL constraint failed: subjects_subject.owner_id

So I tried by another way:

```
form = NewSubject()
#API request   
subject = form.save(commit=False)
subject.owner = request.user
#Another fields
subject.teacher = teacher
subject.group = request.user.group
form.save()
```

Now, the form is saved, but I allways get the error:

> **Exception Value**: 'NewSubject' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Comment: Post the complete code relatged to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save data to a form from your view in Django, you'll need to send a dictionary on the form, then validate this data with the `is_valid()` method:

```
form = NewSubject({
    'owner': request.user.id,
    #Another fields
    'teacher': teacher,
    'group': request.user.group
})
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```